# how do I display all markers from the firebase database?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

how do I display all markers from the firebase database?

I have come into the database the data in this form:

[image]

but only what is highlighted in the drawing is displayed! I write the code like this:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    if (!isOnline() && !isNetworkAvailable()) {
    } else {
        Map1 = googleMap;
        Map1.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

        Map1.setMapStyle(mapStyleOptions);
        Map1.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(this);
        Map1.setOnMyLocationClickListener(this);
        if (Map1 == null) {
            Map1.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }
        startCurrentLocationUpdates();

        mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
                DatabaseReference uidRef = rootRef.child("Markers");
                Map.clear();
                ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        for(DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                            String latitude = ds.child("latitude").getValue().toString();
                            String longitude = ds.child("longitude").getValue().toString();
                            String bus = ds.child("bus_station").getValue().toString();
                            Log.d("TAG", latitude + ", " + longitude);
                            LatLng location = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(latitude), Double.parseDouble(longitude));

                                Map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.img_4662878)).position(location).title(bus));
                            }}}}

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        Log.d("TAG", databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
                    }
                };
                uidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);


                mHandler.postDelayed(this, delay);
            }
        }, delay);
    }}
```

tell me how to display all markers from the database correctly?

error:

```
2020-04-22 23:10:12.031 18972-18972/by.sviter.stop E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: by.sviter.stop, PID: 18972
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.trim()' on a null object reference
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1838)
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
    at by.sviter.stoprevizor.tabs.maps.MapsFragment$3$1.onDataChange(MapsFragment.java:337)
    at com.google.firebase.database.Query$1.onDataChange(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:179)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:75)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:63)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:55)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6718)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:495)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `dn4O ... mgG2` is the `uid` of the authenticated user, to get the values of the latitude and longitude properties, please use the following lines of code:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference uidRef = rootRef.child("Markers").child(uid);
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String latitude = dataSnapshot.child("latitude").getValue(String.class);
        String longitude = dataSnapshot.child("longitude").getValue(String.class);
        Log.d("TAG", latitude + ", " + longitude);
        LatLng location = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(latitude), Double.parseDouble(longitude));

        //Do what you need to do with the location
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d("TAG", databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
uidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The result in the logat will be:

```
53.9148950..., 27.4380507...
```

**Edit:**

According to your comment:

> how to show all the tags?

Please use the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference markersRef = rootRef.child("Markers");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String latitude = ds.child("latitude").getValue(String.class);
            String longitude = ds.child("longitude").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("TAG", latitude + ", " + longitude);
            LatLng location = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(latitude), Double.parseDouble(longitude));

            //Add the location to a list of locations
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d("TAG", databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
markersRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The result in the logcat will be:

```
// ...
// ...
53.9148950..., 27.4380507...
```

Comment: constantly gives an error: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.trim ()' on a null object reference at LatLng location

Comment: When using exactly my code, there no way you can get such an e error because I have never used `trim()`. You can edit your question and add the changed code, so we can take a look at it. Leave a message when you're done.

Comment: Your code is fully working! thanks! but it shows the marks only those that I put! But how to show all the tags ??

Comment: @user3711927 In that case, please see my updated answer and tell me if it works.

Comment: does not work! writes an error: java.lang.String java.lang.String.trim () 'to refer to an empty object

Comment: @user3711927 At which particular line of code are you getting that error?

Comment: LatLng location = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(latitude), Double.parseDouble(longitude));

Comment: Please edit your question and add the entire code that you are using. I cannot see any trim() call in my code that can potentially produce that error.

Comment: noticed that if I logged in with my account and there are records in it, then the database gives out only my records, but does not see others at all! and if you go under your account and there are no entries in the database yet, then he sees the rest, but cannot display, from there there is an error!

Comment: According to which code you are using, you are getting results from your record or from all records. What's the error?

Comment: I need to display all entries

Comment: You should remove the call to `.child(firebaseAuth.getUid())`, in order get all results. See my second solution. Does it work this way?

Comment: no error gives: java.lang.String java.lang.String.trim () at LatLng location

Comment: Please add the entire message and the line at which it occurs.

Comment: At which line of code does this error `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.trim()' on a null object reference` occur? As I see in your code, you are still using `.child(firebaseAuth.getUid())`, which is not correct.

Comment: LatLng location = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(latitude), Double.parseDouble(longitude));

Comment: Still calling `.child(firebaseAuth.getUid())`, will never help you solve the issue.

Comment: only my markers are shown with it, but without it it gives an error and nothing works

Comment: If you are using the **EXACT** same solution I have provided you in the "Edit" part, is it something printed out in the logcat?

Comment: in logcat comes Null, Null

Comment: As you said, you can get the data for the logged-in user, as highlighted in the screenshot. So the initial problem is solved. Regarding the second one, I suggest you post a new question using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.

Answer (score 0):

After the scope of DataSnapshot for loop has ended you can manipulate the contents of the DataModel object using the getters and setters which you should have implemented.

If this does not work. Check if you mMarkers1 object is pointing to the correct class, or change the addListenerForSingleValueEvent to addValueEventListener.

Answer (score 0):

You should you use addValueEventListner instead of addListenerForSingleValueEvent

You must run a for loop to get all data like...

DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
rootRef.child("Markers").addValueEventListner(new ValueEventListner{

@Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot snap : dataSnapshot.getChildern()){
               cast into your model class
            }
        }

```
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
```

});